# How can I create a content based router in asp.net web api

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have a project where I need to route Http Post messages to specific Rest api based on the body. The body can be both xml and json and I don't know the message type up front so I need to unpack the message and inspect parts of it to be able to route it to the correct endpoint.

I was thinking that I could configure some sort of routing rule which could check for the occurrence of one or more property values in the message, but I am not sure what would be the best way to unpack the message and check for those property values.

Does anyone know if there are any libraries that already does this or could I go for RegEx or something to create the rule?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand you need to resend the message based on its type: XML or JSON. You probably could do this by checking the header.

If the clients implement POST correctly they should include `Content-Type` header which should be either `application/json` or `application/xml`, or maybe `text/json`, `text/xml` which is used less often.

Then you can check this header and resend `Request.Body` stream further

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> Post()
    {
        var contentType = Request.Headers.ContentType.FirstOrDefault();
        Trace.TraceInformation(contentType);

        if (contentType == null)
            return BadRequest();

        // get uri
        var uri = contentType == "application/json" ? "/json" : "/xml";

        // resend stream
        var response = await WriteHttpClientStream(uri, contentType, Request.Body);

        // send response back
        await WriteResponseStream(statusCode: 201, contentType, await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync());

        // just to return something
        return new EmptyResult();
    }
```

And if you need to use some data in your body to decide where to route, you probably should read it entirely and parse JSON/XML to find out where to route.